# How can i post my data to facebook

Tags: 7, social-network

I am a new Drupal user, and have the [Drupal for Facebook](https://drupal.org/project/fb) module installed on a Drupal 7 site.

Right now, I have one template file in use, and would like share this data with Facebook.

Is this possible?  I do not see how to do this with the FB module.

Comment: Can you clarify what "share this data" means?  Do you want to click something and have the page appear on your timeline?

Comment: yes @MPD. I want to share the data having in tpl file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the [social media module](https://drupal.org/project/socialmedia)

> The social media module helps integrate your website with social media
>   sites such as Twitter, Facebook and Google+. It provides an
>   centralized way of managing social media profile information and
>   plug-in widgets such as follow and share buttons.

or [sharethis](https://drupal.org/project/sharethis)

> Integration with the ShareThis social bookmarking utility on selected
>   node types.

Comment: sharethis module i used and it posting only site url on my wall.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use the **[Facebook OAuth module](https://drupal.org/project/fboauth)**.

> This module provides authentication services and an API to perform actions against Facebook. This module allows users to login to Drupal through the service commonly known as "Facebook Connect". This module is built with simplicity and flexibility in mind, it provides login services (and does it well), and an API for performing any other actions you may want to write yourself to query against Facebook's APIs.

Features:

1. One-click login through Facebook.
2. Automatic import of user e-mail and profile information during initial login.
3. Integration with Profile module to map Facebook data to Profile fields. (Drupal 6)
4. Integration with Field module to map Facebook data to fields on users. (Drupal 7)
5. A flexible and direct API for modules to get authenticated and query Facebook's APIs (plus extensive documentation).
6. Extensive permission settings for Facebook data retrieval.
7. The ability to de-authenticate or unlink a Facebook account from a Drupal account.
8. Does not require any external libraries or downloads.

For more detail about the module you could go through the README.txt of this module.